# How to get the excel input name as attachment in c#

Tags: c#, email-attachments

I am creating a program to generate the .xls file.

```
xlWorkBook.SaveAs(AttachedFilePath.Trim() + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmm") + ".xls", 
                  Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, 
                  misValue, 
                  misValue,
                  misValue, 
                  misValue, 
                  Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, 
                  misValue, 
                  misValue, 
                  misValue, 
                  misValue, 
                  misValue);
```

Then in another function,

I used Attach API

```
attachment = new Attachment(AttachedFilePath.Trim() + 
                            DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmm").ToString() + ".xls");
```

How I can retrieve the .xls in attachment.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean. Do you think you could make the question a bit clearer?
If you are creating an .xls and attaching it to an email why do you need to retrieve it?

Comment: My mistake :D what I mean is when I attach the Excel file, DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmm") is the Excel file name, so in Attachment, which name I should use to make as an attachment?

Comment: Can't you just create the name in a variable and then use that variable throughout the code?
Like: var myName = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMdd_hhmm").ToString() + ".xls";

Comment: I can't because I have to generate the Excel file daily and sent that particular Excel file as an attachment. So I only can name as "Date, Time" and made an attachment as "Date, Time"

Comment: Yes, keep the naming but use the variable so you know what to attach is what I meant. As long as it's in the same code it shouldn't be problem right?

Comment: Give me other solution bro. This one can't do it :(